# WordPress Visual Composer Single Image Custom Link Not Working

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I am using Visual Composer to edit my homepage on WordPress.
I added a Single Image, set the "On click action" to "Open custom link", put in the link URL and set target to "New window".
On the site, the link doesn't show up. In the source HTML, there is no  tag, just the image.
On other images on the page, there is a link  tag for the image, but they cannot be edited in Visual Composer - the changes don't reflect on the site.

[image: settings]

Answer (score 1):

I Justifying your issue...it is happens some time when Visual Composer Plugin Or its Add-ons Plugin are not respond correctly...
So Please activate these Plugins after Deactivating...!